# Calling a method from the class that created a thread, in the thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method that I want to call in RunnerClass, in a non-static way in ThreadClass.

```
public class CallingClass{
    CallingClass(){
        ClassTwo thread = new ClassTwo();
        thread.start();
    }

    public void someMethod(){}

}

public class ThreadClass extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        //Some thread logic
        CallingClass.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Obviously this won't work. The method is not static (and I'm not allowed to make it static), but in the above example I'm trying to access it in a static way, if only because I feel it best represents what I would like to do.
If it makes sense, I would like for the thread to be able to notify the instance of CallingClass that it needs to call someMethod()

Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: what u want to do and what u want to achieve is not clear

Comment: I would like to have a way for the thread to tell the instance of CallingClass which is running the thread to run someMethod()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating `ClassTwo` constructer that gets a parameter with `CallingClass` type?

```
public class ThreadClass extends Thread{
    CallingClass callingClass;

    public ThreadClass(CallingClass callingClass) {
            this.callingClass = callingClass;
    }
    public void run(){
        //Some thread logic
        callingClass.someMethod();
    }
}
```

And create `ClassTwo` like this:

```
public class CallingClass{
    CallingClass(){
        ClassTwo thread = new ClassTwo(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void someMethod(){}

}
```

Comment: Marking as accepted as I feel this is probably the better of the two solutions since you're separating the classes in to their own files, although in my case using an inner class works better since CallingClass has numerous private methods and variables I need and am not allowed to edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use ThreadClass as an inner class of CallingClass and call the mothod directly.

```
 public class CallingClass{
    CallingClass(){
        ClassTwo thread = new ClassTwo();
        thread.start();
    }

    public void someMethod(){}

    public class ThreadClass extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        //Some thread logic
        someMethod();
    }

}

}
```